# Regex match "/24af786e" letters and numbers

Tags: regex

I have this url `http://localhost:64685/Forum/Runner/runner_job/24af786e`

I would like the `regex` to check if the url, has a `/` followed by 8 x letter or numbers (like in the url) at the end of the url.

this is my best attempt so far, and I know it not good or correct: `/[^/A-Z]{9}/g`

Could someone guide me in the right direction?

**Edit**

How i run the regex,

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"/\/[^\W_]{8}$/");
Match match = regex.Match(url);
if (match.Success)
{
    url.Replace(match.Value, "");
}
```

Comment: use this: `/\/[a-zA-Z0-9]{8}$/`

Comment: Or `/\/[^\W_]{8}$/`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew your regex returns false if i use it with my url

Comment: Check this nice tool https://regex101.com/

Comment: @PeterHansen: Are you working with ASCII only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"/[^\W_]{8}$");
// Or, to make it match only ASCII letters/digits:
// Regex regex = new Regex(@"/[^\W_]{8}$", RegexOptions.ECMAScript);
url = regex.Replace(url, "");
```

No need to check for a match before replacing with a regex. Note that you used a `String.Replace` method, not a `Regex.Replace` one and did not assign the new value to `url` (strings are immutable in C#). See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%2F%5B%5E%5CW_%5D%7B8%7D%24&i=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A64685%2FForum%2FRunner%2Frunner_job%2F24af786e).

**Details**:

- `/` - a literal `/`
- `[^\W_]{8}` - exactly 8 letters or digits (`[^\W_]` matches a char other than a non-word (`\W`) and `_` chars)
- `$` - end of string.

Pass the `RegexOptions.ECMAScript` option if you need to only match ASCII letters/digits.

Comment: Any difference between `[^\W_]` and `[a-zA-Z0-9]`? If not, then the latter is more explicit in my opinion.

Comment: @sp00m: See my bottom note. There is a difference since in C# shorthand classes are Unicode-aware by default, but we can turn it off with a dedicated option. Also, `[\w-[_]]` is also a readable .NET compatible construct that can be used instead of `[^\W_]`. Spelled out variant is also good to use.

Comment: So yours will match more chars, such as `à` or `ô`, right?

Comment: If you do not pass `RegexOptions.ECMAScript`, yes.